# With eslint-webpack-plugin@2.4.1, how do you use eslint's cache?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, eslint

After switching from eslint-loader, our initial watch builds have slowed down substantially due to the lack of caching. Is there a way to use eslint's cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESLint's node api has `cache` and `cacheLocation` keys in it, and setting those like

```js
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ESLintPlugin({
      cache: true, 
      cacheLocation
    })
  ]
}
```

enables caching like `eslint-webpack-loader`'s old caching behavior.